# cannot log in to ubuntu 14.04 following installation

Tags: 14.04

Total newbie. downloaded Ubuntu 14.04 and installed it on Toshiba satellite L300 laptop.  At login, enter password, screen goes blank briefly, then returns to log in screen.
Tried installing Ubuntu 15.10 on same machine. Even worse. Log in OK but all I get is a pink screen  with no icons to click on. Go to console and I can enter login name but will not type anything when try to I enter the password. Does this mean I am stuck with crappy Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

No, you are not stuck with Windows 10. When you log in at the console login prompt, you will not see the password echoed, even with stars. That is the way it's been with *nix forever, or at least since I've been around.

Have you tried a live boot distro? These permit you to try out the distribution without writing to your hard disk. It may help to diagnose your installation problem. Looks like your hardware is on the older side of life, you could try an earlier version of Ubuntu. I found 10.04 to be a solid distro on my Pentium desktop.

Comment: Not showing the start when typing the password has a very good reason - somebody watching your screen can not see how many keys you press, and when. Without the stars, even someone watching your fingers can not easily tell which keys you actually press, and which you only touched.

Comment: Downloaded and installed ver. 10.04 and now working properly Now hopefully I can learn about Linux. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Can you login into a Guest Session?

Login via console (CTRL + ALT + 1-6) (the password is being typed, just not shown. no worries there.).

Now, type this:

- `cd ~`
- `rm .Xauthority`
- Reboot and retry logging in

Hopefully this will do the trick. Comment if it works. If it doesn't, just try a fresh install. Maybe something messed up the install the previous time. In a fresh install, I'd recommend you to take the manual route:

[How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Its kinda sad your first experience with Ubuntu is this convoluted. Usually, it is a pretty simple affair. Good luck,Tony!